# ¿Porque no se muestra mi lista de datos en el ListView?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy tratando de crear una vista con una lista de registros que ya tengo en la base de datos, estoy trabajando con `fragment`, el cual tengo tengo un `ListView` donde quiero mostrar el código del producto y descripción del producto, a lo hora de compilar solo me muestra el interfaz mas no los registros que están almacenados.

**listViveres.php**

```
<?php 
 include('conexion.php');

  $result = array();
  $result['t_viveres'] = array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_viveres";
  $response = $mysql->query ($sql);

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
   $index['codigoViveres']      = $row['1'];
   $index['descriProducto']     = $row['2'];
   $index['tipoClasificacion']  = $row['3'];
   $index['cantidad']           = $row['4'];
   $index['unidadMedida']       = $row['5'];
   $index['fechaRegistro']      = $row['6'];
   $index['fechaCaducidad']     = $row['7'];

array_push($result['t_viveres'],$index);

 }

 $result["success"]="1";
 echo json_encode($result);
 mysqli_close($mysql);
?>
```

**list_viveres.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_codigo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangulo"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_producto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Descripción de producto"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_lista_viveres.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="FragmentAlbergues.Lista_viveres">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/id_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Lista_viveres.java**

```
public class Lista_viveres extends Fragment {
ListView listView;
 AdapterVivere adapter;

public static ArrayList<Vivere> vivereArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
String Url ="http://192.168.4.32/LogisHuman/listViveres.php";
Vivere vivere;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_viveres, container, false);


    return vista;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.id_listView);
    adapter = new AdapterVivere(getActivity(),vivereArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mostrarLista();

}

public void mostrarLista(){
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           vivereArrayList.clear();
           try {
               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
               String sucess = jsonObject.getString("success");
               JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("t_viveres");

               if (sucess.equals("1")){
                   for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String codigoViveres = object.getString("codigoViveres");
                       String descriProducto = object.getString("descriProducto");
                       String tipoClasificacion = object.getString("tipoClasificacion");
                       String cantidad = object.getString("cantidad");
                       String unidadMedida = object.getString("unidadMedida");
                       String fechaRegistro = object.getString("fechaRegistro");
                       String fechaCaducidad = object.getString("fechaCaducidad");

                        vivere = new Vivere(codigoViveres,descriProducto,tipoClasificacion,
                                cantidad,unidadMedida,fechaRegistro,fechaCaducidad);
                        vivereArrayList.add(vivere);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                   }

               }

           }catch (JSONException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(request);

    }
    }
```

**AdapterVivere.java**

```
public class AdapterVivere extends ArrayAdapter<Vivere> {
Context context;
List<Vivere> viveresList;

public AdapterVivere(@NonNull Context context, List<Vivere> viveresList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_viveres,viveresList);
    this.context = context;
    this.viveresList = viveresList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView,  ViewGroup parent) {

    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_viveres,null, true);
    TextView textcodigo = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.id_codigo);
    TextView textproducto = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.id_producto);

    textcodigo.setText(viveresList.get(position).getCodigoViveres());
    textproducto.setText(viveresList.get(position).getDescriProducto());

    return vista;
}
}
```

**Captura donde solo me muestra el interfaz más no los datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te muestra algún error la consola? Te está llegando bien la petición desde la app al server? Te llegan los datos a la app? Has hecho debug para ver exactamente que está haciendo tu código?

Comment: @FranCámara en consola no me sale ningún error

Comment: @FranCámara gracias de todos modos, ya corregí ese detalle y ya se me muestran los datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi solución fue, en lista_viveres.java implemente un objeto de vivere de la siguiente  manera:

```
                       Vivere vivere  = new Vivere();

                       vivere.setCodigoViveres(codigoViveres);
                       vivere.setDescriProducto(descriProducto);
                       vivere.setTipoClasificacion(tipoClasificacion);
                       vivere.setCantidad(cantidad);
                       vivere.setUnidadMedida(unidadMedida);
                       vivere.setFechaRegistro(fechaRegistro);
                       vivere.setFechaCaducidad(fechaCaducidad);
```